# Looping an entire p5js script

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, p5.js

I was wondering if it is possible to run the following code on the p5js web editor or within VS code multiple times and change the parameters a, b, A, B, H from an array of predefined values every time it runs and save the PNG image locally.  My aim is to let the script run and generate a wide range of plots with these parameters varying. This is a simplified version of my problem so running the loop within the draw loop is not possible.  Is there a way to loop the entire script? Many thanks in advance.

```
//fixed
Sb = 0.3;
Vb = 1;
// noprotect

t = 0;
dt = 0.1 / 2;
t2=0

//want to vary
a = 0.03;
b = 0.04;
A = 20;
B = 20;
H = 0.15;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 1000, WEBGL);
  colorMode(HSB, 1);

  console.log(width);
  background(H, Sb, Vb);
}

function draw() {
  
  for (i = 0; t < 200 * TAU; i++) {
    W = A * sin(a * t) * B * sin(b * t );
   
  
    strokeWeight(2);
    point(t-width/2,W)

    

    t += dt;
  }
 saveCanvas(join(['Im', 1], '_'), 'png')
  noLoop()
  
}
```

Comment: Why couldn't the sketch run in the draw loop? 
You can move 'background()' into draw. What other pitfalls are there?

Comment: About the saveCanvas: I didn't find a solution to save a file to a local directory without running a server. 
I described my solution here: https://discourse.processing.org/t/saving-canvas-to-a-file/11027/5

Comment: @PhilippLehmann the piece has interactivity that happens during the draw loop.  I know I could cut that out for this case when I just want the final result but given this is to validate the script I have concerns it will not be enough to fully test functionality.

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876) -- looping the entire script isn't what you need, you just need a way to re-initialize relevant state at some point later once the `draw()` function has satisfactorily generated a single plot. So write a loop inside the draw function with new values for each of these variables (what values are desired is unclear -- use an array or a random number generator, probably) and call `saveCanvas` after each trip through the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop the whole script, do something like this:

```
function setup(){

  createCanvas(1000, 1000, WEBGL);
  colorMode(HSB, 1);

  background("white");
  
  iteration(0.03,0.04,20,20,0.15);
  
}

function iteration(a, b, A, B, H){

  const Sb = 0.3;
  const Vb = 1;
  let t = 0;
  const dt = 0.1 / 2;
  const t2 = 0

  background(H, Sb, Vb);

  for (let i = 0; t < 200 * TAU; i++) {
    W = A * sin(a * t) * B * sin(b * t );

    strokeWeight(2);
    point(t-width/2,W)

    t += dt;
  }
  saveCanvas(join(['Im', 1], '_'), 'png');
}
```